# hello.js Work Login But publish is not work

Tags: asp.net, authentication, scope, share, hello.js

Sorry, My english is poor.

I'm make some home page, that is gamedict.com.

this home page .Net framework 4.5 and Webform.

Oauth login is work very well. but hello.api(.... 'share'...) is not work.

this page have master page.

```
<button onclick="OauthLogin('google');" title="Signin to Google" class="zocial icon google"></button>

<button onclick="OauthLogin('facebook');" title="Signin to Facebook" class="zocial icon facebook"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OauthLogin(network) {
        hello(network).login();
    }

    function SignOut(){
        var network = $("#hidNetwork").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AjaxControls/AjaxSignOut.aspx",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                hello(network).logout().then(function (){
                    location.reload();
                });
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("getAuthentication code:" + request.status + "\n" + "message:" + request.responseText + "\n" + "error:" + error);
            }
        });
    }

    hello.on('auth.login', function (r) {
        // Get Profile
        hello(r.network).api('/me').then(function (p) {
            var isAuthenticated = <%=Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString().ToLower() %>;
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/AjaxControls/AjaxAuthentication.aspx",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        Name: p.name,
                        Email: p.email,
                        AccTocken: p.id,
                        OauthType: r.network
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        location.href = "/Default.aspx";
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert("getAuthentication code:" + request.status + "\n" + "message:" + request.responseText + "\n" + "error:" + error);
                    }
                });
            }else {
                $("#hidNetwork").val(r.network);
            }
        });
    });

    hello.init({
        google: CLIENT_IDS.google,
        facebook: CLIENT_IDS.facebook,
        twitter: CLIENT_IDS.twitter
    }, {
        scope: 'email',
        redirect_uri: 'http://www.gamedict.com/'
    });

</script>
```

this Code is work.

this is view page

```
<button onclick="GameShare('google');">Share Google</button>
<button onclick="GameShare('facebook');">Share Facebook</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isBoardGame = $("#<%=IsBoardGame.ClientID%>").val();
        if (isBoardGame == "true") {
            $(".BoardNotUse").hide();
        }
    });

    function GameShare(network) {
        hello(network).login({ scope: 'publish' }, function () {
            alert(network);
            // Post the contents of the form
            hello.api(network + ':/me/share', 'get', { link: "<%=string.Format("http://{0}{1}",HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl) %>" }, function (r) {
                if (!r || r.error) {
                    alert("Whoops! " + r.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Your message has been published to " + network);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

this page "share" is not work.

My site url: http://www.gamedict.com/PC/test11

That page bottom has button for share.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Given `hello.api( path, method, data )` the value of `method` needs to be `"post"` - not `"get"`